# Why is the output of the second snippet not 40 even though there is a reference to type?

Tags: python, import, sys

```
import sys
print(sys.getrefcount(type))
```

Output: 39

---

```
import sys
A = type('A', (), {})
print(sys.getrefcount(type))
```

Output: 39

---

Why is the output of the second snippet not 40 even though there is a reference to `type`?

Comment: Why do you think there's a(nother) reference to `type`?

Comment: @jonrshape ```A = type('A', (), {})```

Comment: But that's just calling `type`. It would be different if you had `A = type`.

Comment: Your reference isn't to the function, in other words, it's to whatever the function returns.

Comment: Maybe the result of `type(A)` giving `<class 'type'>` is misleading.

Comment: @jonrshape ```import sys;
a = type(1);
print(sys.getrefcount(a))``` — This considers the reference "a".

Comment: @jonrshape Is that the same in the case of ```a = type(1)```?

Comment: @Matthias Hey, Is ```__init__``` and ```__new__``` part of the ```object``` class (through which all classes inherit)?